# mysql: for a single column count number of rows for occurrence of specific values

Tags: mysql, select

I am writing a report using MySQL query.  It has multiple columns that I report.  Within that, there is one column containing many different values (only one value pre row). There are two specific values in that column that I need to count.  The final results are then grouped by type:

Table

```
ID Name  has passed  Type  
 1  abc      yes (1)   z  
 2  xyz      yes (1)   x  
 3  cde      no  (0)   y  
 4  abc      yes (1)   z  
 5  cde      no  (0)   z  
 6  xyz      no  (0)   y
```

My expected result is:

```
For Type x  
 total records = 1  
 yes count = 1     
 total abc = 0  
 total cde = 0  

For Type y  
 total records = 2  
 yes count = 0     
 total abc = 0  
 total cde = 1  

For Type z  
 total records = 3  
 yes count = 2   
 total abc = 2  
 total cde = 1
```

Notice that we don't count name xyz or any other name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    type,
    COUNT(*) AS total_records,
    COUNT(IF(has_passed, 1, NULL)) AS yes_count,
    COUNT(IF(name = 'abc', 1, NULL)) AS total_abc,
    COUNT(IF(name = 'cde', 1, NULL)) AS total_cde
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    type
```

Comment: PERFECTO!  Thanks much, Zane.  I though I tried this query before I came to StackOverflow.  It does exactly as I desire.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (don't have access to a database for testing right now, sorry)... Maybe something like this would work (assuming you're storing 0 and 1 for "passed")?

```
SELECT
   type,
   SUM(passed) as "Yes count",
   SUM(case when name = 'abc' then 1 else 0 end) as "Total abc",
   SUM(case when name = 'cde' then 1 else 0 end) as "Total cde",
   COUNT(1) as "Total records"
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   type
;
```

Comment: Argh... Was beaten to it I see. I also think my example may be using Oracle syntax. The gist of it is the same though.

Comment: Though an upside to your solution is that the `CASE` expression is more standard across other DBMSs while `IF` is mostly MySQL-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I do try to keep to the standards when possible. MySQL's version is shorter in this case, but the standard way with `CASE`is more legible IMO. Anyway, either does the job :O)

Comment: Thanks guys but no-go with MySQL. It reports "an error" with no detail.  I also tried replacing sum with count.  What about a sub-query?

Comment: I am now home and made a quick table identical to the one in your question - and my query worked fine just copying and pasting it from my answer.